# Jest spy on all es6/typescript class methods when manual mocking class

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using manual mock for mocking a typescript Class and i'm re implementing all of its methods and i want jest to automatically spy on all of its methods.

**Expected Result**
I wish to be able to automatically spy on all methods.
means that every method I define in the mock manual i will be able to spy on it without having to use `jest.fn()` on each of the methods.

**Actual result**
TypeError: Cannot read property 'calls' of undefined

**Code**

api/services/user-service.ts

```
import User from "../../models/user";

export default class UserService {
  getUser(): User{
    return new User('testname', 'testName@tes.com');
  }
}
```

api/services/**mocks**/user-service.ts

```
import User from "../../models/user";

export default class UserService {
  getUser(): User{
    return new User('testname', 'testName@tes.com');
  }
}
```

/tests/user-service.test.ts

```
import UserService from "../api/services/user-service";
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";

jest.mock('../api/services/user-service');

it('Should get test user', ()=>{
  const userService = new UserService();
  expect(userService.getUser()).toEqual({name: 'testname', email: 'testName@tes.com'});
  expect(mocked(userService).getUser.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
})
```

/jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  roots: [
    "<rootDir>"
  ],
  testMatch: [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.ts",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).ts"
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest"
  },
};
```

EDIT :

It seems that jest has a problem handeling es6 classes and imports properly.
I can't call mockImplementation simply by doing this in the `__mock__`

```
jest.genMockFromModule('../user-service').getUser.mockImplementation
```

Also tries using the `mocked()` from ts-jest

i'm getting error `Property 'playSoundFile' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)`

And let's say i skip this line, jest does not recognise the default export properly and i'm getting

`UserService_1.default is not a constructor`

Comment: If you want its methods to be automatically mocked, don't mock it in `__mocks__`. These mocks are mutually exclusive, and manual mock doesn't use Jest spies, so getUser is not a spy.

Comment: @EstusFlask Can't I use the automatic mock in the ` __mocks__` ?

Comment: They stop being automatic this way because... they aren't automatic anymore. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks  . Automatic and manual mocks can be combined with https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestcreatemockfrommodulemodulename . What problem are you trying to solve? You could just provide a valid mock with Jest spies in `__mock__`.

Comment: @EstusFlask Ok so I can use createMockFromModule in  `__mock__` but how can I mockImplementation for its methods?

Comment: If `getUser` is generated by createMockFromModule, it will be Jest spy and thus have mockImplementation, etc.

Comment: @EstusFlask I edited the post. appreciate if you take a look.